# How do I stop the network icon in system tray from blinking on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, icons, notification-area

I've been using XP since forever and had that network icon always in the tray, but  for some reason it's really bothering me now. Maybe because I'm using Windows 7 on my other two machines where the networks icon doesn't blink at all.

Please tell me there's a way to switch off the blinking. I don't want to remove it entirely from the tray as I do like to have quick access to network settings via the tray icon.

Comment: do you mean the LAN connection icon? it has lights, so i guess that's animated. What is the point. I just uncheck the "show" it box. I then assume that I am connected. And if i'm not, then I get the icon with a red x in it and a "disconnected" popup. And sometimes it can give me a "limited or no internet access" picture. And if all is fine then it's not there at all. I did one use a good program to show network activity in the system tray, I think called analogx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always turn on 'Hide inactive icons' and set the network icon to 'Always Hide'. That way when you want to access it you can just hit the << button and click the icon, which is much quicker than getting to it through control panel or any other explorer function.

To do it right click on the taskbar and click Properies. Make sure 'Hide Inactive Icons' is ticked, then click 'Customize'. Find the network icon in the list and choose 'Always Hide', then OK out of the screens. Now its easily accessible but not flashing constantly on display.

Comment: I'd forgotten you could do this in XP. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you right click -> properties, I'm pretty sure there's a checkbox for "Animate icon during network activity", or something to that effect. Sadly it's been a while since I used XP so I can't verify the exact steps.

Comment: Nope, there's no such setting. There are options to either show/hide the icon and an option for notifications when there is limited or no connectivity.